# Compute $\int _Lye^{xy}dx +xe^{xy}dy$ from $(0,0)$ to $(2,1)$, $L : x = 2ye^y$

Tags: calculus, integration

**Compute** $$\int _Lye^{xy}dx +xe^{xy}dy$$ from $(0,0)$ to $(2,1)$, $L : x = 2ye^y$

**What I've tried:**

If I input $0,0$ then I get $(0,0)$, if I input $(2,1)$ I get $(2e,1)$.

I also know that $P'_y = Q'_x$.

But I couldn't manage to solve this anyways. I tried to break it to two integrals because it'd be easier to go from $(0,0)$ to $(2e,0)$ and from $(2e,0)$ to $(2e,1)$ but I still didn't get to the solution which is $e^2-1$. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that if we let $c(t) = (x(t), y(t))$ and  $F = \langle F_1,F_2 \rangle$ then we can rewrite the line integral as;

$$\\$$
$$\int_c F \cdot ds = \int_{t=a}^{t=b} \langle F_1(c(t)), F_2(c(t)) \rangle \cdot \langle x'(t), y'(t) \rangle \ dt = \int_c F_1 \ dx + F_2 \ dy$$

$$\\$$

You can parametrize $L$ by letting $y = t$ then $x = 2te^t$ and so you have $L(t) = (2te^t,t)$ where $0 \leq t \leq 1$. Now just proceed by the above.

Comment: I tried to do that, its pretty long and disgusting. I'm trying that now

Comment: It is clear that the author of the original problem did not intend the student to even consider the path $L$ at all and that the author himself cared so little of the path $L$ that he did not even double-check to make sure that the path actually went from $(0,0)$ to $(2,1)$. In actuality, the line integral has no solution for that path between the two given points. For exact equations the definite integral is independent of path but that does not mean that the path does not have to contain the two points in question.

Answer (score 1):

Since $$ye^{xy}dx +xe^{xy}dy=d(e^{xy}),$$ 
we have 
$$\int _L ye^{xy}dx +xe^{xy}dy=\int _L d(e^{xy})=e^{xy}|_{(0,0)}^{(2,1)}=e^2-1.$$

Comment: Nice one. Is there another way to approach this?

Comment: The upper endpoint is $(2 e,1)$.

Comment: @Ron Gordon: Bounds for $(x,y)$ are $(0,0)$ and $(2,1)$.

Comment: How do you figure?  When $y=1$, $x=2 (1) e^{1}$.

Comment: Maybe the solution is $e^{2e} - 1$? @RonGordon

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWSa: yes.

Comment: @RonGordon I figured. Thank you. Is there another way to approach this except alans one and Faraad's one? Because making one of the variables as $t$ always works and might be quite long and make me do mistakes in the exam. and with the alans approach it doesn't always work. Any ideas for another approach?

Comment: Oh so my approach did work, the one I posted in the thread. because I got to $e^{2e} -1$. @RonGordon

Comment: @Ron Gordon No, it is exact differential, so it doesn't depend on path, only on endpoints, which are $(0,0)$ and $(2,1)$.

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS: My advice is to look to this solution as an opportunity to recognize WHEN you can easily use the Fundamental Theorem.  The parametric approach is ugly in this case, but it should lead you to the same result.

Comment: @RonGordon I see. Thank you.

Comment: @alans: While you are right, you are also misreading the OP's intent.  The point $(2,1)$ does not lie on the curve he prescribed, so he intended the upper endpoint to be $(2 e,1)$.

Comment: @RonGordon Exactly. $(2,1)$ is not on the curve.

Comment: @Ron Gordon I see that now, thanks for pointing that out.